# Click on hidden elements

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I´m testing with nightwatch and  I have to test a list of 19 links.
The problem here is that the page is only showing the 1st 5 elements, to see the rest it´s necessary to click a button to make the list slide and show the following links. I´ve tried with `IF-ELSE`, if visible click on link, if not click the button to slide, but is not working. Any help? Thank you.

```
 .execute(function () {
   return document.querySelectorAll('.wrap>section:nth-of-type(2)>.tsr-container .tsr-module-product').length;},
      function (result) {
         total_downL = result.value;
         console.log("Number of download buttons: " + total_downL);
             for (i = 1; i <= total_downL; i++) {
                 (function (i) {                                   
                    browser.waitForElementVisible('.wrap>section:nth-of-type(2)>.tsr-container .tsr-module-product:nth-child(' + i + ') ', 2000,
                      function (visible) {
                         if (visible.value != false) {
                            browser.click('.wrap>section:nth-of-type(2)>.tsr-container .tsr-module-product:nth-child(' + i + ') .btnDownload')
                                   .waitForElementVisible('.modal-header .close', 2000)
                                   .click('.close')
                                   .pause(2000);}             
                         else {
                            browser.waitForElementVisible('.wrap>section:nth-of-type(2)>.tsr-container .tsr-next',2000)
                                   .click('.wrap>section:nth-of-type(2)>.tsr-container .tsr-next')
                                }
                              }
                          )
                          }(i)
                         )
                       }
                   }
          )
```